# Issues with retargeting app for windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am trying to retarget my app for windows 8.1 and I am experiencing some issues. 
I am getting an error that personally I do not recognize nor I found any information online

```
Syntax Error found in XBF generation    AdSettingsFlyout.xaml
```

I do not have an AdSettingsFlyout.xaml file in my project and I suppose is one of the files that get built with the project due to Windows Ad SDK. I did not find a windows 8.1 SDK. How can I fix the issue? I need some of the 8.1 functionality in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft reported an error with the Ad SDK flyout here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-sdk-api-reference-adsettingsflyout-known-issues(v=msads.10).aspx

Windows 8.1 Advertising SDK is included in the VS2013 package or you can get it as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-windows-prereqs(v=msads.10).aspx

Try removing any references to the Advertising SDK from your projects before upgrading.