# WP8.1 SDK. Error adding controls

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-express, windows-phone-8.1

Just recently, WP8.1 Update was released. I decided to get the SDKfrom [Here](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). Everything installed and it's all working but I'm getting errors when adding certain controls. Some of those controls are:

- AutoSuggestBox
- CommandBar
- PivotControl

There could be more but, whenever i add these controls, Visual Studio Express 2013 either freezes for an insanely long time, or gives me the error: `Syntax error found in XBF Generation`

So can someone please clear things for me? How can I get these to work. Am I missing anything?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check if some resource you are using has any type different of **x** in your .xaml files.
Like this:

```
    <System:String x:Key="AppName"> <!-- this could produce the error 
because the "System" namspace being called instead of "x" -->
```

Try to change things like the one above to this:

```
<x:String x:Key="AppName">
```

Maybe this can help you.
I found this information [here](http://blog.peterritchie.com/?p=1471).

Hope it helps!

**UPDATED:**

Microsoft has released the Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013 and there is a similar issue that has been fixed.

You can try to update your Visual Studio 2013 and check if this issue has gone.

Here is the link to the update: [Update 2 VS 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432/en-us)

Comment: Hey, I've checked and I haven't found any "system" type. Could there be anything else?

Comment: Maybe you are falling in the reported error from Microsoft. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505012/issues-with-retargeting-app-for-windows-8-1

But it seems to be resolved with this update for Windows 8.1 SDK...
Does this happen with every project you try to run? Or just with your specific project?

Comment: It happens to every project. I tested it and yeap. Do you know where i can get the fix. You mentioned something about windows 8.1 SDK?

Comment: Hmm very strange! If I were you, I would reinstall visual studio and Windows Phone SDK... Uninstall Windows Phone SDK and Visual Studio 2013 and then try to reinstall it. This may not be an issue with your projects, but with the SDK installation itself. I know that this is a tough solution, but It can be the quickiest way to try to solve this... If every project casts the problem, then it is sure that is an installation issue.

Comment: I say this because I have the same version as you installed in my computer, and I have a complete Windows Phone project too. I never seen this problem here, so reinstalling Visual Studio and Windows Phone SDK seems to be a good try.

Comment: Yea. I tried the uninstall re-install last night. Still the same problem. This is only for Windows Phone 8.1 SDk not for any other.

Comment: Hmm very strange... Are you still getting the problem? If you want, pvt me with a URL where I can download a sample of your project. I can try to open it here to see if I get the same problem, since I have the same SDK and Windows version as you. I can help you with it if you want, just let me know. :)